# symfony3 chat application using gos socketBundle

Tags: websocket, symfony

i'm developping a chat application using gos socketBundle i'm trying to show connected users using this code in javascript .
when the subscribe is done to the channel connected users always connectedUsers are null?? could any one help me please ?

{{ ws_client()}}

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var websocket = WS.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

    //var websocket = WS.connect("ws://{#{{ wsUrl }}#})");
    websocket.on("socket/connect", function (session) {



        session.subscribe("connected-users/channel", function (uri, payload) {

            console.log(session);
            console.log(payload);
            var connectedUsers = JSON.parse(payload.connectedUsers);
            var newtml = '';
            connectedUsers.forEach(function (user) {
                newtml += '<a name="toggle" class="connectedUserLink" onclick="talkToUser(\'' + user.id + '\', \'' + user.username + '\')">' + user.username + '</a>';
            });
            $('#connectedUserNbr').html(connectedUsers.length);
            $('#connectedUserList').html(newtml);
        });
    });
    websocket.on("socket/disconnect", function (error) {
        //error provides us with some insight into the disconnection: error.reason and error.code
        console.log("Disconnected for " + error.reason + " with code " + error.code);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting the logs in the console? Are the connected users being shown in the payload?

Comment: yes but i always get an empty array

Comment: It sounds like you need to fix your code in the "connected-users/channel" endpoint if it's returning an empty array always.